# How can I fix error when inserting php form into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to save data from a form into a mysql database. I can connect to the database but for some reason I can't get it to insert the data into the database. I have a feeling it might just be a syntax error I'm not seeing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
PHP

// Get values from form 
 $Nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
 $Email=$_POST['Email'];
 $Telefono=$_POST['Telefono'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $leads(Nombre, Email, Telefono)VALUES('$Nombre','$Email','$Telefono')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

HTML

  <form action="leads.php" method="POST">
       <input placeholder="Nombre" type="text" name="Nombre" maxlength="40"/>
       <input placeholder="Email" type="text" name="Email" maxlength="100"/>
       <input placeholder="Teléfono" type="text" name="Telefono" maxlength="9" pattern=".{8,}"    required title="8 numeros mínimo"/>
       <button class="btn-cita" name="cita">Hacer Cita</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` use this to get the error and posted the error here.

Comment: You should always try first echo $sql and look for if output is correct. This is kind of most basic debugging you could do when dealing with sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do. You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are using undefined variables in your query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $leads(Nombre, Email, Telefono)VALUES('$Nombre','$Email','$Telefono')";
                  ^^^^^^---undefined
```

Producing a query something like

```
INSERT INTO (Nombre, etc...
```

Comment: Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I just realized that I had written the name of the table 'leads' instead of using the $tbl_name variable I had set up. 

$sql="INSERT INTO $leads(Nombre, Email,     Telefono)VALUES('$Nombre','$Email','$Telefono')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);